# Spaces between parameters in a Powershell command

Tags: command-line, powershell, whitespace

I want to know why when I let spaces between paramters in a powershell command I have errors :

*With* space : (don't work)

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth, screenheight
Expression GET non valide.
```

*Without* space : (work)

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth,screenheight
ScreenHeight  ScreenWidth
```

Is that normal ? Because I see a lot of commands on the internet given with spaces!

---

**Update 27/01/2016 Version Detail**:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10240.16384
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   10.0.10240.16384
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

Both way (with and without space) work with CMD but only the second way (without space) work with PowerShell (see below screen shots):

[image: Cmd.exe]

[image: PowerShell]

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running and on what version of Windows? These commands are BOTH valid in command prompt (not PowerShell in my setup), but BOTH are invalid in my setup in PowerShell in my environment. More detail of your environment configuration may be helpful. If you have a chance to add a screen shot  or a link showing a working and non-working example, that may be helpful as well.

Comment: `$PSVersionTable` to find the version you are using.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish : I wish I answered to your question in my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma is an array operator in PowerShell. So your command:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth, screenheight
```

have following meaning: invoke `wmic` with three arguments: string `desktopmonitor`, string `get` and array with two strings `screenwidth` and `screenheight`. Since `wmic` is native application, PowerShell have to transform arguments into command line. PowerShell use space as separator when transforming array into command line. So, resulting command line would be following:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth screenheight
```

You can see that by typing following command:

```
cmd /c echo wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth, screenheight
```

Starting from PowerShell v5 there is one special case here. If array provided directly (not as subexpression) and there is no spaces between commas and array elements, then PowerShell use comma as separator when transforming arrays into command line.

```
PS> cmd /c echo 1,2,3 (4,5,6) 7,8 ,9
1,2,3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This command:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth,screenheight
```

qualify for this special case and resulting command line would be following:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth,screenheight
```